# Email in IOS Gmail App Not Aligning Correctly

Tags: html, css, gmail, html-email

I keep having alignment issues when putting two blocks together in my email for gmail. On all other mail clients it looks the way that it's supposed to look -- either floating next to each other or stacking right on top. On iOS in Gmail, it's trying to stack and float next to each other at the same time which makes it look wonky.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
<tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FAFAFA" class="pad-modBlogs" id="modBlogs">
        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" style="padding: 56px 24px 42px 24px;">
                    <h2 style="color: #4a4a4a;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight: 700;
                                font-size: 24px;line-height: 38px;margin: 0 0 18px 0;">From the Blog</h2>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </table>


        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" class="fluid">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table width="280" border="0"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width: 280px;" class="fluid" role="presentation" float="left" align="left">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" style="padding: 0px 0px 24px 0px;">

                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
                          <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="https://www.digitalelement.com/proxy-and-vpn-data-enhances-cybersecurity-effectiveness-in-2022/" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.digitalelement.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/iStock-479801072-1-1200x600.jpg" width="280px" height="152" style="display: block;" class="img-max fade-img"></a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="blogs">
                                            <p class="copy-16-cat" style="color: #a0a1a3;font-size: 14px; font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-weight: 500;
                                              line-height: 24px; margin: 0; text-transform: uppercase">Security &amp; Privacy</p>

                                            <h4 style="color: #666261;font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif;
                                              font-weight: 600;font-size: 16px;line-height: 26px; margin: 10px 0 10px 0"><a class="blog-link" href="https://www.digitalelement.com/proxy-and-vpn-data-enhances-cybersecurity-effectiveness-in-2022/?utm_source=GovernmentNurtureEmail1&amp;utm_medium=email+nurture&amp;utm_campaign=government_nurture_2022&amp;utm_id=Government_Nurture_2022&amp;utm_content=blog+1" style="color: #4a4a4a; text-decoration: none" target="_blank"><span class="txt-un" style="line-height: 26px;">Proxy and VPN Data Enhances Cybersecurity Effectiveness in 2022</span></a></h4>

                                            <p class="read" style="color: #a0a1a3;font-size: 14px;font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight: 400; line-height: 20px;margin: 0">6 min read</p>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                </table>

                            </tr>
                    </table>


                        <table width="280" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width: 280px;" class="fluid" role="presentation" float="right" align="right">
                            <tr>
                              <td align="center" style="padding: 0px 0px 24px 0px;">
    

                                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
                                    <tr>
                                      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="https://www.digitalelement.com/the-role-of-proxy-data-in-fighting-cybercrime/" target="_blank"><img class="img-max fade-img" height="152" src="https://www.digitalelement.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/AdobeStock_75838140-1200x600.jpeg" style="display: block;" width="280px"></a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="blogs">
                                            <p class="copy-16-cat" style="color: #a0a1a3;font-size: 14px; font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-weight: 500;
                                              line-height: 24px; margin: 0; text-transform: uppercase">Security &amp; Privacy</p>

                                            <h4 style="color: #666261;font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif;
                                              font-weight: 600;font-size: 16px;line-height: 26px; margin: 10px 0 10px 0"><a class="blog-link" href="https://www.digitalelement.com/the-role-of-proxy-data-in-fighting-cybercrime/?utm_source=GovernmentNurtureEmail1&amp;utm_medium=email+nurture&amp;utm_campaign=government_nurture_2022&amp;utm_id=Government_Nurture_2022&amp;utm_content=blog+2" style="color: #4a4a4a; text-decoration: none" target="_blank"><span class="txt-un" style="line-height: 26px;">The Role of Proxy Data in Fighting Cybercrime</span></a><br>
                                            <span class="mobile-hide"><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span></span></h4>

                                            <p class="read" style="color: #a0a1a3;font-size: 14px;font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight: 400; line-height: 20px;margin: 0">4 min read</p>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Can you show us what you want it to look like, in both mobile and desktop, and, what the error is in Gmail ios? I.e. screenshots? Also, you reference a class="fluid" and other classes, but you have not given us the code for the CSS

Comment: @Nathan -- Thank you so much for your response! I actually was able to figure it out by declaring max-width's for the "fluid (what I had declared as the media query for mobile)" class. Gmail is stupid.

Comment: Gmail may be removing the `<style>` block/s because you have somtehing in there it doesn't like, such as square brackets or * or fancy css selection methods, or typos.